# como conectar una bd en mysql utilizando nodejs

Tags: java, json

¡Hola! Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con Node.js y necesito conectar una base de datos MySQL. ¿Alguien podría proporcionarme un ejemplo básico de cómo hacerlo y darme algunos consejos sobre las mejores prácticas?

Comment: Posible motivo de [cierre](/help/closed-questions): _La pregunta está buscando recomendaciones de libros,herramientas,librerías u otros recursos externos_. Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Claro, en [npmjs.com/mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) encontrarás guía espiritual, consejo personal, las mejores prácticas y todo el pack completo que amerita tu problema. Aquí sólo obtendrás ayuda cuando hayas asistido a tu primera batalla con el código y seas derrotado dignamente en dicho campo de batalla, entonces nos mostrarás tus heridas de guerra con un [mcve] y nos dirás exactamente cuál fue la causa de la pérdida de la batalla, cuál era el resultado esperado y cómo hiciste frente al desafío. Te sugiero leer [ask] y realizar el [tour].